# Dynamically Change Style of Text

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am making a portfolio website for my self.I need to add a small functionality.What i need is to change change text style after some interval say 1 second.
So i have a array like

```
  const dev = ["blah1", "Blah2", "blah3"];
```

Say,Now what i want to add a underline to each element of the array after some interval. Like blah1, then blah2 , so on.And when it reaches blah3 it restart back to blah1 and it continues like that.

so what i did is following:

```
import React from 'react'

const Hello = () => {
  const [currentCount, setCount] = useState(10);
  const timer = () => setCount(currentCount + 2);


  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentCount <= 0) {
      return;
    }

    const id = setInterval(timer, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(id);

    // return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, [currentCount]);

  const dev = ["blah1", "Blah2", "blah4"];
   const items = dev.map(p => {
    return (
      <p>{p}</p>
    )
  })
    return (
        <div>
            Hello {items}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Hello
```

I created a setInterval function which starts from 10.But i am not able to use this to get the functionality i want.Maybe this is not the way to do it.Please suggest any solution.
Thanks.

Comment: `const Untitled-1` are you sure this is working and you are not getting errors like "_Missing initializer in const declaration_"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setInterval` and then update the active index

```js
const App = () => {

   const dev = ["blah1", "Blah2", "blah4"];
   const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
   useEffect(() => {
      const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
         setActiveIndex(v => ((v + 1) % dev.length));
      }, 1000);
      return () => {
         clearInterval(intervalId);
      }
   },[]);
   const items = dev.map((p, index) => {
    return (
      <p style={{ textDecoration: index === activeIndex ? 'underline' : 'none' }}>{p}</p>
    )
   });
   return (
      <div>
          Hello {items}
      </div>
   );
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply,
but it is not working. It underlines the first element then removes it.Basically it is not Looping over again and again.

Comment: @RishavSinha Sorry, there was a typo. I used `/` instead of `%` in `(v + 1) % dev.length`. Updated the code, hope it will work now